# Interrupt Coalescence

Tags: interrupt

Thought it is known to occur for high speed networks like Gigabit Networks, still wanted to know what are the typical speeds at which we are looking for this phenomenon to occur. Can it occur on networks which support 5-10 Mbps max speed.

Answer (score 3):

Interrupt coalescing is a very interesting concept and has a lot of detailed aspects to it. Take a look at this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEftEMt-f7c) and this [article](http://virtualirfan.com/history-of-interrupts) for the background on how interrupts work and how to make sense of them.

In short, there are two variables that control them in most interrupt coalescing schemes:

- Maximum Interrupt Delay Latency (MIDL). Like a deadline: once the
  controller receives a hardware completion, how long it is allowed to
  wait till it will interrupt the processor. The idea being the delay
  is to limit the number of times a second an interrupt can occur and
  to get lucky with more hardware completions arriving within a
  specified time period.
- Maximum Coalesce Count (MCC). The number of
  hardware completions before the IO controller will provide a delivery of interrupt to the processor.

Fascinating history of interrupts especially the bit about how Edsgar Djikstra was freaked out 'bout them (the video discusses this too).

Answer (score 2):

When a device generates more than about 5000 interrupts per second, interrupt coalescing makes sense.  Coalescing boosts throughput at the cost of transaction latency, which makes sense for bulk data movement.  Latency sensitive workloads may not want coalescing at any line rate.  Anyway, a 10Mbps wire receiving full size packets is ~650 packets per second, so probably not worthwhile.  A 100Mbps wire can do 10x that rate so interrupt coalescing starts to make sense.  At 1Gbps, coalescing becomes very important for throughput.

The most direct answer to your question as to whether or not you will see coalescing depends if your specific network device supports this feature.  A platform cannot unilaterally impose interrupt coalescing on a device.